# not quotes in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm having a string

```
var str = "hello -- (world)";
```

using regex and replace

```
str.replace([a-z],"0");
```

replaces all the alphabets. but i need to replace other than alphabet.

Comment: What is the expected string after the replace?

Comment: "i need to replace other than alphabet". What do you mean by this?

Comment: other than alphabets , other than [a-z].....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replace([^a-zA-Z], "0");`

Comment: Dont we have to wrap the expression inside slashes, as: str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/, "0");

Comment: You might be right, I focused on the regex and just copied the syntax the OP used in his post. I do not do much JavaScript.

Comment: Actually `str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '0');`, or you'll only replace one.

Answer (score 1):

I would say

```
str.replace(\W, '1');
```